# Proxy Pattern: how is it more efficent that creating the real object?

Tags: java, design-patterns, proxy-pattern

In the following example, from wiki books https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Science_Design_Patterns/Proxy

I am not sure how this is faster/more effiecent than just creating the real object and using display image from it. Becuase the proxy creates the real object anyway within the displayImage method?

```
//on System B
    class ProxyImage implements Image {

        private RealImage image = null;
        private String filename = null;
        /**
         * Constructor
         * @param FILENAME
         */
        public ProxyImage(final String FILENAME) {
            filename = FILENAME;
        }

        /**
         * Displays the image
         */
        public void displayImage() {
            if (image == null) {
               image = new RealImage(filename);
            }
            image.displayImage();
        }

    }
```

Surely the proxy pattern wouldnt save memory as it needs to instantiate two objects (proxy and real) rather than just one (real) if you didnt use proxy?

Comment: This would save memory when declared, that's about it. Probably not worth it, but you could add bind() and release() methods for dynamic memory allocation to images.

Comment: How would it save memory? I dont think i understand this pattern very well

Comment: I didn't understand this pattern either... Just read the answer.

Comment: If you read the entire example, e.g., `ProxyExample` class on that page, you'll see the answer:
`IMAGE1.displayImage(); // loading necessary` followed by `IMAGE1.displayImage(); // loading unnecessary`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link you posted (emphasis mine):

> The proxy class `ProxyImage` is running on another system than the real image class itself and can represent the real image `RealImage` over there. The image information is accessed from the disk. Using the proxy pattern, the code of the `ProxyImage` **avoids multiple loading of the image**, accessing it from the other system in a memory-saving manner.

In short: it doesn't save memory, it speeds up the application because you don't need to access to disk every time to read the real image.

This is proven in this part of the code:

```
public void displayImage() {
    //if image is not loaded into memory
    if (image == null) {
        //then load it, go to disk only once
        image = new RealImage(filename);
    }
    //now it is in memory, display the real image
    image.displayImage();
}
```

---

To have a better understanding of this problem, let's change the definitions of the class and the interface:

```
public interface Image {
    String getName();
    byte[] getData();
}
```

Now, the `RealImage` class that will always seek for the data in disk, in case the file doesn't exist (it was deleted or renamed):

```
public class RealImage implements Image {
    //implements all the operations going to disk...
    private String fileName;
    public RealImage(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        String name = "";
        //fancy operations to seek for the file in disk (in case it has been deleted)
        //read the data from file in disk
        //get the name
        name = ...;
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public byte[] getData() {
        byte[] data;
        //again, fancy operations to seek for the file in disk (in case it has been deleted)
        //read the data from file in disk
        //get the image data for displaying purposes
        data = ...;
        return data;
    }
}
```

And now, our good `ProxyImage` that will act as a proxy for a `RealImage` to save the highly costly task of going to disk every time by saving the data into memory:

```
public class ProxyImage implements Image {
    private String fileName;
    private RealImage realImage;
    private byte[] data;
    private String name;
    //implements all the operations going to disk...
    public RealImage(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        //in case we don't have the name of the image
        if (this.name == null) {
            //use a RealImage to retrieve the image name
            //we will create the instance of realImage only if needed
            if (realImage == null) {
                realImage = new RealImage(fileName);
            }
            //getting the image from the real image is highly costly
            //so we will do this only once
            this.name = realImage.getName();
        }
        return this.name;
    }
    @Override
    public byte[] getData() {
        //similar behavior for the data of the image
        if (this.data == null) {
            if (realImage == null) {
                realImage = new RealImage(fileName);
            }
            //highly costly operation
            this.data = realImage.getData();
        }
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

Thus reflecting the *goodies* of using a proxy for our `RealImage`.

Comment: So basically instead of creating an image that you may not use, you only create it if you are wanting to display it?

Comment: @RNI2013 yes, and if you need it several times, you won't create it again from disk, you will reuse it.

Comment: How will you re-use it? would it not be just as efficent though to create the real object when you want to display an imagine and use its displayImage? Becuase by using the proxy you are actually instantiating two objects?

Comment: @RNI2013 you will always have a trade off: speed vs memory usage. If you want speed, you will loss memory, if you want to save memory, you may loss speed. In this case, since you have enough memory to use for your application (nowadays most devices have at least 2 GBs) and because creating this additional object is like 4 KBs (or similar, depending on the JVM implementation), then the trade off for the speed to gain is worth.

Comment: OK thanks, so it is not a big problem to create two objects? I just dont see the advantage of proxy over just creating the original object and using one of its methods? I dont mean in this example i mean in general

Comment: @RNI2013 well, you could think of a proxy object like an object that will behave like your object but can do more things for you. For example, Hibernate framework uses proxies objects for you when declaring lazy loading for specific data, usually Collections like `List`. This means, if you have an entity, let's say, `Customer`, and you only need to display his/her name and date of birth, why would you need to load all the data from lots of related tables like `CustomerType`, `Invoice`s, `Agreement`s, and on... from database? This way you save both memory usage and network latency time.

Comment: But surely when you create the real object within the proxy then the real object will use up just as much memory as if you created it without a proxy?

Comment: @RNI2013 yes, but it won't create it unless you need it. Again, take the example from Hibernate from my last comment. If you don't need to load that data, then the proxy won't do anything at all, so you save memory and network latency from a database request, note that any I/O operation is highly costly.

Comment: Yeah i understand, but if you didnt need it then you could just not create it at all? Sorry im just confused lol

Comment: @RNI2013 in this case, it is easy to apply what you say and the proxy pattern may not be needed. Note that you should not use an application pattern unless you really have a problem to solve.

Comment: @RNI2013 answer updated. Let me know if now is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of this particular proxy appears to be to implement what's called 'Lazy Loading.'  It doesn't actually read the file and create the image in memory until some other piece of code actually attempts to display it.  This could save a lot of time and memory compared to putting images into memory that you never use!

In small examples it's easy to think "Well I could just program smarted and not load the silly thing."  But imagine a bigger system where you are stuck with an API that takes a `List<Image>` as an argument, but only actually draws one when the user clicks the filename or something.  This could be a significant boost.